# Time consuming for insert record in Solr Index

Tags: solr

We are using ***add*** method of **org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient** for insert data into Solr Cloud Index. In specific scenario we need to insert record of around 3 MB document into Solr which takes 5-6 seconds.

Can we use any alternate to improve performance?

Comment: Are you actually indexing all the content (i.e. how much is processed)? You're getting into file sizes where actually reading the file from disk and transferring it across the wire is taking up significant time as well. If you check the log on the receiving Solr node, you should see a `QTime` entry (or your response in SolrJ should have a method for that as well) which will give you the time actually spent inside Solr for processing.

Comment: Hello. "data" is very generic. If you were to pass a properly formatted, schema-accordant json doc I will be faster than passing a PDF with lots of processors in the chain. Your question is very open.

Comment: Hello @MatsLindh, thanks for your reply. We have checked on our side and found that time consume in process (QTime) not in network latency or any other process.

Comment: Hello @s1m3n, thanks for your replay. We prepared JSON based on schema fields. Total size of JSON string is around 3 MB.

Comment: Since the time is spent inside Solr, you'll have to try to reduce the amount of processing and data you're running through for each field. If you have processing steps that isn't necessary, remove them. If you have filters that generate lots of tokens, make sure that you actually need them or devise ways to work around their limitations. It's impossible to say much without a lot more details in your question. You can also index multiple documents in parallel and run several nodes to perform indexing as separate shards (in a cluster setting).

Comment: @MatsLindh, thanks for your input. In our case we do index for one document only at a time. It contains large no. of fields which leads to size of 3 MB. We have declare a **dynamicField** in our schema file i.e. "data*". One document can have multiple fields with prefix of "data" i.e.: data/studentname, data/studentname/address along with other static fields.

Comment: Would you please provide a sample record and the related schema.xml? I could not tell anything about the processing performance without knowing what and how it is processed.